# Wordpress sticky posts first and then order alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type named "products". This CPT has a boolean field named "featured".

My product loop is ordered alphabetically at the moment:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

if ( ! empty( get_queried_object() ) )
{
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_categorie',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => get_queried_object()->slug
        ),
    );
}
```

But how can I manage it that all the featured products (with boolean = true) are shown first and then all the other products (still alphabetically)?

Comment: You're using `WP_Query`?

Comment: Yes, that correct.
<?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use 2 arguments and use separately, this example should work depending on the meta value of 'featured' key in database:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
);

    if ( ! empty( get_queried_object() ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_categorie',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => get_queried_object()->slug
            ),
        );
    }
// Featured products args
$args1 = $args;
$args1['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'featured',
        'value'    => 1, // Make sure that's 1 is the repersentation of true in db
        'compare'    '='
    ),
);
// Not freatured product args
$args2 = $args;
$args2['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'featured',
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'featured',
        'compare'    'NOT EXISTS'
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query` allow to use multiple orderby with an array:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'meta_key' => 'featured',
    'orderby' => array('meta_value' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See: [Order & Orderby parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) : **Multiple orderby/order pairs** and **'orderby' with 'meta_value' and custom post type**